# Should we split data into several periods before calculating class weight? (Advances in Financial Machine Learning)

Tags: algorithmic-trading, machine-learning, classifier

In the book, section 4.8 class weights, Marcos suggests applying class weight, which I agree because sometimes you have more bullish price action than bearish price action e.g. 52% of the time is bullish.

But he doesn't talk about splitting the dataset. My intuition is that if the training set has 2 years of data, and the 1st year is bull market whereas 2nd year is bear market, simply applying the same class weight throughout might not be good enough.
Because it implies decreasing the sample weight of bullish samples in 2nd year too. But samples in 2nd year are already in bear market, so it doesn't make much sense to try to make it more bearish.

I'm not sure how to formalize this intuition yet. Do you think we need to split dataset into periods to apply different class weight for each period? And how would you go about it?

Comment: Does he really not address predicting probabilities and proper scoring rules? Class weights are largely a way of wrestling with the predicted probabilities so they look nice when they are compared to a default threshold, rather than giving meaning to the predictions. // [Further reading with additional links within](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any)

Comment: @Dave He talked about uniqueness sample weight, time decay, and class weight. He said that all can be combined. I'm concerned specifically about the class weight case. Thanks for the links about class imbalance problems. I've been wrestling with the idea myself and struggling fundamentally that's why I don't know whether to split the data or not. Financial data has so I feel like it needs splitting. For example, you can apply class weight to first year, then apply another class weight to second year.